# Plotting Derivative of data in matlab

Tags: matlab, derivative

I am pretty new to Matlab and i have some Current Vs times stored under a structure in a matlab file. 
What i am trying to plot is current vs time along with the first derivative of it. (di/dt). I used the diff function but the plot seems to be really wierd.
I know it simple but can anyone explain it.

THanks in advance.

Comment: Add: Data + plot + what you have tried + what you expect, and it might turn out to be a good question =)

Comment: Take into accoant that to approximately compute the derivative *dy/dx* you should use `diff(y)./diff(x)` (not just `diff(y)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have a structure **S**,

**S.t** is the time vector and  **S.I** is the current vector in each time in **S.t**.
(both should be in the same length **N**).

Now, if you want to approximate the derivative:

```
dt = diff(S.t); % dt is the time intervals length, dt is N-1 length. 
dI = diff(S.I);  
derivative = dI./dt; %derivative is memberwise division of dI by dt 
plot(t(1:end-1),derivative); % when you plot both vector should be in the same length:
                             % t(1:end-1) is the same as t except the last coordinate
```

I think this should work

Comment: Thanks i have fixed it now. I knew my mistake. I had not used the plot as you said and it ended up throwing mismatch in length or a weird plot. Seems fine now though. :)